# Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDefualt is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-hook-form, react-functional-component

I'm new to React and js in general and I'm following a crash course on React and got stuck on this error at some point in the course.
This is the error message that I'm getting is for the preventDefault method, which I have used to prevent the page from refreshing.

here is the 2 file concern

```
import { useState } from "react"

export function NewTodoForm({onSubmit}){
    const [newItem, setNewItem] = useState("")
  function handleSubmit(e) {

    e.preventDefualt()
    if (newItem === "") return
    onSubmit(newItem)
    
    setNewItem("")
  }
return (
    <form className="new-item-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-row">
          <label htmlFor="item"> New Item</label>
          <input value={newItem} onChange={e => setNewItem(e.target.value)} type="text" id="item"></input>
        </div>
        <button className="btn" >
          Add
        </button>
      </form>
)
}
```

```
import "./styles.css"
import { useState } from "react"
import { NewTodoForm } from "./NewTodoForm"

function App() {


  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])
  

  function addTodo(title) {
    setTodos(currentTodos => {
      return [
        ...currentTodos,
        { id: crypto.randomUUID(), title, completed: false },
      ]
    })
  }
  console.log(todos)
  return (
    
    <>
      <NewTodoForm onSubmit={addTodo}/>
    
      <h1 className="header">
        Todo List
      </h1>
     
      
      <ul  className="list">
      {todos.map(todo => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-key
        return (
          <> 
          <li key={todo.id}>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox"  checked={todo.completed}/>
            {todo.title}

          </label>
          <button className="btn btn-danger">
            delete
          </button>

        </li>
        </>
        )
        
      })}
      
      </ul>
    </>



  )
}

export default App
```

I tried to use other methods rather than preventDefualt, but none of them works, from preventing from refreshing the page.

Comment: It's a typo: `preventDefault` not `preventDefualt`.

Answer (score 5):

You have a typo, your code is

```
e.preventDefualt()
```

It should be

```
e.preventDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in handleSubmit function where e.preventDefault() has been misspelled. Also don't forget to make "default" export of your function.